# In CUDA, is it guaranteed that the default stream equals nullptr?

Tags: cuda, default-value, cuda-streams

In CUDA's `driver_types.h` we have:

```
typedef __device_builtin__ struct CUstream_st *cudaStream_t;
```

And in `cuda_runtime.h` we have, in many places, default-initialized stream parameters. For example:

```
template<class T>
    static __inline__ __host__ cudaError_t cudaLaunchKernel(
    const T *func,
    dim3 gridDim,
    dim3 blockDim,
    void **args,
    size_t sharedMem = 0,
    cudaStream_t stream = 0
)
```

How safe is it to assume the default stream is `(cudaStream) nullptr`?

Comment: out of curiosity: why do you need to know that?

Comment: @m.s.: I haven't noticed a `cudaGetDefaultStream()` function, and I want to do something like `my_stream = condition ? foo() : cudaGetDefaultStream()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is documented to be the case in multiple places:

1. [Programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#default-stream):

> Kernel launches and host <-> device memory copies that do not specify any stream parameter, **or equivalently that set the stream parameter to zero**, are issued to the default stream.

2. [For example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g85073372f776b4c4d5f89f7124b7bf79), `cudaMemcpyAsync`:

> The copy can optionally be associated to a stream by passing a non-zero stream argument.

It seems quite safe to assume that the default stream is equivalent to `(cudaStream_t) 0`

Note that you can call out the default stream specifically with an argument other than zero, using `cudaStreamLegacy` (or `cudaStreamPerThread`) as described [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency/).  Interestingly, in CUDA 11.4, `cudaStreamLegacy` is a `#define` in driver_types.h as follows:

```
#define cudaStreamLegacy ((cudaStream_t)0x1)
```

This probably makes sense, since it is always associated with the legacy default stream, whereas a stream argument of 0 will reference the current system-defined default stream, whether that happens to be the legacy default stream or the per-thread default stream, as indicated in the previously linked blog.

Similarly, `cudaStreamPerThread` is defined to be `(cudaStream_t)2`.